# How to download video from Twitch?

Tags: download, file-download, twitch

Is it possible to download a video from Twitch? I've found a couple of online-services but they provide premium-limited funtionality (allow you to download only a part of the video and if you want the whole thing - you need to pay)

Does anyone know some good and free app that does this?

Thank you!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Youtube-dl is a powerful command line tool that will let you download from a lot of different video websites/services including twitch.

Comment: Wow, I just gave it a try and it worked! Thanks a lot! ;-)

Comment: for some reason I can't upvote you're answer, but thanks again!

Comment: You need 10 reputation before you can upvote.